# How To Prevent The User Who Is Granted Of DBA Role From Granting DBA To Other User

Tags: oracle

How To Prevent The User Who Is Granted Of DBA Role From Granting DBA To Other User?
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2766663_1.html  this link say something,but i can not log in.
How To Prevent The User Who Is Granted Of DBA Role From Granting DBA To Other User?
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2766663_1.html  this link say something,but i can not log in.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, not without tampering with the built-in DBA role. The role contains the `GRANT ANY ROLE` system priv and that would permit someone with the DBA role to grant the DBA (or any other role) to others, even without the admin option. If you need a restricted DBA role, create your own and customize it.

Omit from this new role: `GRANT ANY ROLE`, `GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE` privs and the `IMP_FULL_DATABASE` and `DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE` roles (as they include `GRANT ANY ROLE` within them), and don't grant the new role to others with admin option.